# Recyclerview items starts overlapping after its size is changed via ConstraintLayout and ConstraintSet animations

Tags: android

My layout is `ConstraintLayout` and hierarchy is like this:

There is top view area that takes half of the screen, below that a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. In this `ViewPager` there are 3 tabs which contain a `RecyclerView`. When any `RecyclerView` is scrolled, top area collapses to 10% of height and `ViewPager` expands. Due to this `RecyclerView` expands too. However, after this expansion, `RecyclerView` items stars overlapping too.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ConstraintLayout and enable animation for each item when has changed. Let disable that issue will be resolved.

`android:animateLayoutChanges="false"`